# Sending user info to Mailchimp automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mailchimp

What do I have to do in order to send a user's name and email to my Mailchimp account automatically as soon as they sign up on my application (Devise)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use [Gibbon](https://github.com/amro/gibbon), a mailchimp wrapper to work with their api

```
  def add_to_mailchimp(email_address, first_name, last_name)
    list_id = "your_list_id"
    gibbon = Gibbon::Request.new
    # only need the md5_email if you want to use 'upsert' (find_or_create_by) or 'update', not 'create'
    md5_email = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(email_address)

     gibbon.lists(list_id).members(md5_email).upsert(body: {email_address: email_address, status: "subscribed", merge_fields: {FNAME: first_name, LNAME: last_name}})
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

you probably should use the regular User after create hook

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :send_to_mailchimp

  def send_to_mailchimp
    # send data to mailchimp
  end
end
```